# Android with firebase, how to push data on children?

Tags: android, firebase

How do you add push() to the waypoint children? Can't get it right..

```
    Map mWaypoints = new HashMap();
    mWaypoints.put("latitude", mCurrentLatlngOnCreate.latitude);
    mWaypoints.put("longitude", mCurrentLatlngOnCreate.longitude);

    Map mParent = new HashMap();
    mParent.put("routeID", "my route id");
    mParent.put("routeName", "my route name");
    mParent.put("Waypoints", mWaypoints);

    myFirebaseRef.push().setValue(mParent);
```

Here is the current result, but want to have the push id below Waypoints.

```
    -KGNWnjgXPC0kHYiOKG7
       Waypoints        // <---  Want to get the unique below here
          latitude: 31
          longitude: 421
       routeID: "my route id"
       routeName: "my route name"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`push()` is a pure client-side operation, that you can call separately. So:

```
Map mWaypoints = new HashMap();
mWaypoints.put("latitude", mCurrentLatlngOnCreate.latitude);
mWaypoints.put("longitude", mCurrentLatlngOnCreate.longitude);

String key = myFirebaseRef.push().getKey();
Map mWayPointsMap = new HashMap();
mWayPointsMap.put(key, mWayPoints);

Map mParent = new HashMap();
mParent.put("routeID", "my route id");
mParent.put("routeName", "my route name");
mParent.put("Waypoints", mWayPointsMap);

myFirebaseRef.push().setValue(mParent);
```